# How to see if there are other users in the database with the same username - JWT Django REST authentication

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

I want to know how to see whether there a two or more users with the same username when signing up. I refer to the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@dakota.lillie/django-react-jwt-authentication-5015ee00ef9a) on Medium by Dakota Lillie.

I asked because the tutorial hasn't got any error handling in it and because I am not much of React expert.

To give you an idea about the thing that happens without handling the signup is that -  when I enter a username that is already existing it logs me in.

The other thing is that - when logged in (valid account) the home screen says for example - Hello, John.
But here for some reason, it says Hello, A user with that username already exists.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all users in the database, and specify a  where clause to check if the username the user is trying to input already exists in the database, if it exists throw an error

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in code, please?